# How can i restart an unresponsive app?

Tags: 8.0, apps

I'm trying to set up Mayhem Remote, and it's stuck trying to connect to my computer. I want to restart the app, but I can't find a way of doing so. Pressing back, windows, or search suspends the app and takes me to my home screen. But when I re-open the app, it resumes right where it left off. How can I close the app complete, and restart from scratch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way. Windows Phone 8 will close the oldest app in the list if you try to open more than 8 apps.

**EDIT**

Now with Windows Phone 8.1 and above you can just hold back button and click "x".

Comment: Not ideal, but it's better than restarting my phone. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. In Windows 8 to close all apps the is an option in PC Settings->General->Delete history. But is easier close one by one instead of go to far.

Comment: You can also flick an app in back button view to close it.